# Postman test of spring ArrayList getmapping response

Tags: spring-boot, postman

I have a Spring Boot application that has a getmapping returning an ArrayList.  This all works fine and it returns the arraylist as a json object in the body. I am trying to write a postman test on the response to verify the length of the arraylist that comes back.  I cant seem to get it to find the arraylist on the object however since there doesn't appear to be any keys.

My Spring Code is:

```
    @GetMapping(value="/getAllCars", produces = "application/json")
    public @ResponseBody List<Car> getAllCars() {  
        return carManager.getAllCars();
    }
```

The response in postman shows

```
[
    {
        "id": "19a94f8d-b1c1-4814-abba-57b1cb319478",
        "name": "car1"
    },
    {
        "id": "4e2568ca-f41a-480d-82b5-acede9109a6d",
        "name": "car2",
    },
    {
        "id": "4e2568ca-f41a-480d-82b5-acede9109a6d",
        "name": "car3",
    },
... (there is 72 total)

]
```

my test code in postman is  is

```
pm.test("CarsLength"  , function(){
    const responseJson = pm.response.json;
    pm.expect(responseJson.length).to.equal(72);
})
```

when i look at the postman console after logging the responseJson and responseJson.length its only logging out the function name and 2.  responseJson[0] and responseJson[1] are both undefined when i log them out as well.

I dont have a key in my response json object is thats whats causing this?  How can I access the objects to verify the length in a postman test?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The mistake is here:

`pm.response.json` --> `pm.response.json()`

Comment: WOW thank you... Lots of the examples I've seen dont have that. I wonder why? That worked though thanks!